# Using PERCENTILE_DISC with Aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to use [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327.aspx) with a number of other built in aggregate functions. The code I am attempting reads like this, but it fails:

```
SELECT
    [DataPoint] AS [DataPoint],
    MIN([Value]) AS [Value MIN],
    MAX([Value]) AS [Value MAX],
    AVG([Value]) AS [Value AVG],
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)
        WITHIN GROUP 
        (ORDER BY [Value])
        OVER 
        (PARTITION BY [DataPoint])
        AS MedianCont
    FROM [Table] AS [Table]
    WHERE ([DataPoint]
        IN (
            ...
        )
    )
    GROUP BY [DataPoint]
```

So this works...

```
SELECT
    Distinct [DataPoint],
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)
    WITHIN GROUP 
    (ORDER BY [Value])
    OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [DataPoint])
    AS MedianCont
    FROM [Table] AS [Table]
    WHERE ([DataPoint]
        IN (
            ...
        )
    )
```

And this works...

```
SELECT
    [DataPoint] AS [DataPoint],
    MIN([Value]) AS [Value MIN],
    MAX([Value]) AS [Value MAX],
    AVG([Value]) AS [Value AVG]
    FROM [Table] AS [Table]
    WHERE ([DataPoint]
        IN (
            ...
        )
    )
    GROUP BY [DataPoint]
```

But when I try to combine them, it wants me to declare `Value` in the `Group By` clause, which I do not want because I want a distinct list of `DataPoint`'s, not a value per `DataPoint`.

```
Column 'Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that using the [over clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), thus creating a 'window function', separates the aggregate function from the select statement.

```
SELECT
    Distinct [DataPoint],
    MIN([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [DataPoint]) AS [Value MIN],
    MAX([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [DataPoint]) AS [Value MAX],
    AVG([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [DataPoint]) AS [Value AVG],
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)
        WITHIN GROUP 
        (ORDER BY [Value])
        OVER 
        (PARTITION BY [DataPoint])
        AS MedianCont
    FROM [Table] AS [Table]
    WHERE ([DataPoint]
        IN (
            ...
        )
    )
```